# Use ARCore with OBJ and MTL files

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, mtl-file, poly-google

When played with the Android [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/) Samples, I noticed that the sample use the next line:

```
mVirtualObject.createOnGlThread(this, "andy.obj", "andy.png");
```

`andy.png` is the PNG file texture to "stretch" over the `andy.obj` 3D object.

I want to replace the model and the PNG file, with items from [Google Poly](https://poly.google.com).

But when downloading an obj file from Poly, I'm getting obj + `mtl` files.

I guess that the `mlt` is the texture file like the PNG, but I can't use it.

Can I convert it to PNG file? Or use `mtl` file in ARCore?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, ARCore does support the direct rendering of .obj files in Java?

Comment: @ManuelTS Yes, it is supported

Answer (score 3):

The .*mtl is the material file that is referenced from the OBJ and defines stuff like textures and lightning configuration. The OBJ loading library used in the ARCore sample is very basic so you have to find a better one or implement the OBJ file loading on your own. Another option would be to use a 3D library for Android that already provides model loading and hides the low-level OpenGL stuff.
For examples of these high-level libraries see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48456836/385536.

Answer (score 0):

For `ARCore 1.8`/`Sceneform 1.8` apps you can use the following 3D file formats:

- **.obj**
- **.fbx**
- **.glTF**
- **.glb**
- **.sfa** (ASCII Sceneform Asset Definition)
- **.sfb** (Binary Sceneform Asset Definition)

As well as the following supported `texture`/`material` file formats:

- **.mtl**
- **.bin**
- **.png**
- **.jpg**
- **.sfm**
- **.mat**

If you can't read in corresponding `mtl` texture, just convert/replace it with the other supported format.
You can use `obj` asset this way:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        mVirtualObject.createOnGlThread(this, 
                                        "andy.obj", 
                                        "andy.png");
        mVirtualObject.setBlendMode(MtlRenderer.BlendMode.Shadow);
        mVirtualObject.setMaterialProperties(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        mVirtualObjectShadow.createOnGlThread(this, 
                                              "andy_shadow.fbx", 
                                              "andy_shadow.sfm");
        mVirtualObjectShadow.setBlendMode(MtlRenderer.BlendMode.Shadow);
        mVirtualObjectShadow.setMaterialProperties(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read 3D asset file");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, ARCore does support the direct rendering of .obj files in Java?

Comment: Not sure. I haven't tried `.obj` directly in ARCore Java. It's for the sake of example only. I usually follow official approach: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets