# What is the SceneKit equivalent for Android?

Tags: android, ios, scenekit, arcore

I created an [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/arkit/) app using [SceneKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit). I want to bring it over to [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar) but using straight OpenGL seems daunting.

Is there a high-level scene graph framework like SceneKit for Android developers that can help to import and render 3D models?

Comment: surely sceneform ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ViroCore](http://www.viromedia.com/virocore) is a SceneKit for Android. With ViroCore you describe scenes at a high level in Java, without having to implement rendering algorithms yourself in OpenGL. It has built-in integration with ARCore, and its rendering feature-set is equivalent to SceneKit.

It's also thoroughly documented, with [development guides](https://virocore.viromedia.com/), a [full Javadoc](https://developer.viromedia.com/virocore/reference/com/viro/core/package-summary.html), and [code samples](https://github.com/viromedia/virocore). A good starting point is trying out this [AR retail code sample](https://github.com/viromedia/virocore/tree/master/ARRetail) -- it's a full ARCore application written with ViroCore.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the LibGDX and ARCore blog too: https://medium.com/@wilkinsonclay/investigating-arcore-with-libgdx-f69b83764118

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali or https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ for this purpose. A good start for Rajawali and ARCore is this blog post https://medium.com/@alex_dennis/intro-to-augmented-reality-development-with-tango-b9ea2923bdea. It's about Tango but as ARCore is based on Tango the concepts and APIs are almost the same.